# Optimizations for ng build at runtime

Tags: angular, docker

I have developed a small Angular app that I have packaged as a container. This app leverages the Angular 'environments' so I can `ng build` build it using various `--environment=` flags (e.g. `test`, `dev`, `prod`).

Given that I want to maintain a single docker image and start with the proper flag at `run` time, I built a small entry point script that basically does `ng build --environment=$UI_ENV` and eventually start nginx.

`UI_ENV` is a variable that I pass to the container at the `docker run`.

This works just fine but the drawback is that the container takes between 15 and 20 seconds to compile the angular app and eventually start nginx (due to the compile time).

I am just wondering if this is the best approach (within the boundaries I have described). Or if this is the best that can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you make an image containing all the environments pre-build? What's the reason you want to rebuild after every image start?

Comment: Mh... the only reason for which I compile at every start is because I keep the nginx root folder the same (the `dist` directory) and in there I put (at `docker run` time) the result of `ng build`. If I am reading you right you are suggesting that I produce the 3 outputs at `docker build` time in 3 different folders and use the input variable to programmatically reconfigure the nginx root folder at `docker run` time?

Comment: that's exactly what im saying :) that will save you a lot of seconds, and your image file will be a lot smaller, because all you need are the files in the `dist` folder. There will be 3 of those folders though, but still a lot lot less, compared to the node_modules you put in there. Scratch that.. you are going to use docker to build it obviously, so you will still need all the files. Anyways yes, do it at `docker build`, and use `run` to change the `root folder`

Comment: Thanks @PierreDuc ... yep that makes total sense. Stupid me for not having thought about it in the first place. Yes size of the container is another optimization I will start to have a look at. Right now it comes in at about 1GB (WOOOT!). I start FROM nginx, then I add angular CLI, NPM, I install the module etc etc etc .. and the end result is 1GB. I am wondering if the newly introduced multi-staging build process is something that I could leverage (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/). Thanks!